# c++ compile error after upgrading from ubuntu 10.10 to 11.10

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-10.10, libjpeg, ubuntu-11.10

I have a program in c++ that was working and compiling on ubuntu 10.10.  However, when i upgraded to 11.10 i started to get this error message:

```
g++ -rdynamic -o ../../../bin/camera Camera.o main.o moc_Camera.o    -L/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -ljpeg -lcfitsio -lavcodec -lavformat -lswscale -lfftw3 -lfftw3f -lcv -lgdal1.7.0 -lmatrox_fake -lbacktrace -lexceptions -limage -limage_display -lio -ljpeg_image -llog -lmetadata -lpipe -lpipebrowser -lplumber -lplumbing -lqt -lserial -ltime -lwebcam -Wl,-R/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib -lQtXml -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread 
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libjpeg_image.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_resync_to_restart'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libplumber.so: undefined reference to `company::pipe::PipeBrowser::PipeBrowser()'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libjpeg_image.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libjpeg_image.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libjpeg_image.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_compress'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libjpeg_image.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_read_header'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libqt.so: undefined reference to `ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler()'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/liblog.so: undefined reference to `Backtrace::add(void*)'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libjpeg_image.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_decompress'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libwebcam.so: undefined reference to `Exception::Exception(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libimage.so: undefined reference to `Exception::Exception(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libimage.so: undefined reference to `Exception::~Exception()'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libjpeg_image.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_compress'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/liblog.so: undefined reference to `Backtrace::~Backtrace()'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libjpeg_image.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_compress'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libjpeg_image.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_decompress'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libjpeg_image.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_set_defaults'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/liblog.so: undefined reference to `Backtrace::print(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&) const'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libimage.so: undefined reference to `Exception::~Exception()'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libimage.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for Exception'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libjpeg_image.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libplumber.so: undefined reference to `ExceptionHandler::handle(Exception&)'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/liblog.so: undefined reference to `Backtrace::trace()'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libjpeg_image.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_write_scanlines'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/liblog.so: undefined reference to `Backtrace::Backtrace()'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libimage.so: undefined reference to `Exception::report(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&) const'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libjpeg_image.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libjpeg_image.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_read_scanlines'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/libimage.so: undefined reference to `IOException::IOException(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/home/myusername/Desktop/project/lib/liblog.so: undefined reference to `checkIO(std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../../../bin/camera] Error 1
```

All the libraries are there.. so im not sure why there are all those undefined references.  Has anyone else encountered this problems with the libjpeg library after upgrading to 11.10 or have any idea on why upgrading would cause this problem?

Comment: my guess is the library got upgraded to a new version?  run nm see what symbols are present in the new library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that all of the .so libraries when they are being compiled they were missing -l(libname) for all the included libraries which is why all those undefined errors where being printed out.  Still wondering why it works without them on 10.10 and not on 11.10...

Answer (score 1):

According to the information found in this [bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=564016), re-installing the JPEG library may solve the problem. The title of the bug is **libwebkit-1.0-2: Undefined symbol: jpeg_resync_to_restart* and here is how the reporter fixed the problem:

> My system appeared to be broken. After reinstalling libjpeg62,
>   libjpeg.so.62 becomes a symlink to libjpeg.so.62.0.0 as expected.
>   Something must be wrong in my upgrade path, but it's not
>   libwebkit's or libjpeg's problem. So, closing this false-alarm
>   bug now.

Comment: I uninstalled it and reinstalled. Its still giving me the same error.